# Is that config option called core.fileMode or core.filemode?

Tags: git

`git help config` mentions both as examples in various lines. I just set both to be sure, but is that setting camel cased or not?

Comment: Well, in git's source, it's not camel case: https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b7ca916fcffafe9cfd967cce87436a9372ae969/config.c#L658.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable names in [git](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#EXAMPLES) are case-insensitive so you can just set core.filemode.